# Limit length of selected array by Mongoose find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here I have a document with an array as one filed in it. Looks like:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    activities:[{
        action:String,
        time:Number,
        extraInfo:{}
    }]
})
```

And now I want to select this array,

```
UserModel
 .findById(user._id)
 .select('activities')
 .lean()
 .exec((err,user)=>{....})
```

but I just need the latest, like 20, activity records.

is there any way to limit the length of selected array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the MongoDB `$slice` operator: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#slice-projection

Mongoose has a helper function to achieve this:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-slice

So, your example become something like that:

```
UserModel
  .findById(user._id)
  .slice('activities', 20)
  .select('activities')
  .lean()
  .exec((err,user)=>{....})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MongoDB $limit operator:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/

Also available in mongoose:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

One example in the website of mongoose:

```
Person.
find({
  occupation: /host/,
  'name.last': 'Ghost',
  age: { $gt: 17, $lt: 66 },
  likes: { $in: ['vaporizing', 'talking'] }
}).
limit(10).
sort({ occupation: -1 }).
select({ name: 1, occupation: 1 }).
exec(callback);
```